# NodeJS/ReactJS: Create downloadable file with string for mobile browser

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, mobile, mobile-safari

I want to create a vCard in the frontend and to make it downloadable (by clicking a button) in a ReactJs Project. I use a NodeJS module called `vcards-js` that creates a string with the content of the desired vCard (v3.0). The thing I am struggling with is to make it downloadable (as .vcf file). I have tried to achieve this with the modules `react-file-download` and `file-saver` but none of them worked properly. Last one worked fine on desktop, but did not manage to provide a download from mobile browsers. Chrome mobile opened a new tab and loaded forever, Safari mobile just opened the string in a new tap, but did not download it as a .vcf file.

Any clues or experiences? Do I need to create the vCard Server-side and provide a download link? Seems too circuitous to me.

If it helps, this is my `file-saver` approach:

```
var FileSaver = require('file-saver');
    var blob = new Blob([card.getFormattedString()], {type: "text/x-vCard;charset=iso-8859-1"});
    FileSaver.saveAs(blob, 'card.vcf');
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm looking over the docs on vcardjs
https://github.com/enesser/vCards-js

you have to have a route on your backend on node to handle the process

It looks pretty intuitive
//save to file
vCard.saveToFile('./eric-nesser.vcf');

Comment: From what I understand, the saveToFile function saves the file on the local file system. This is not what I want to achieve. I want to create this file in the cache/RAM or whatever and make it downloadable (by the choice of the user). In Addition, Writing directly to the filesystem should not work from the client side due to security issues. Nevertheless if I try this approach it throws an error, that `fs`module is not installed (`fs.writeFileSync is not a function`).

Comment: oh I see :) Thank you for clartifying I'm excited to look into this and see if I can help you!~ :D

Comment: I've been thinking about it you could have the route genereate the vcard data with vcards-js and pass it back to the browser on a get

then do something like... I think..

Comment: If you generate the data via the route and have it pass back to you, to the browser and when you receive the data you can just do a simple file save implementation with the browser and have a blank file with the stringified contents from vcards-js saved with the .vcf ending pretty sure you're good to go I just made a touch exmaple.vcf put a string copy of a working vcf and it read it correctly and added correctly :D I hope that solves your issue xD

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get this to work on vue.js by generating a vcf blob using the following code

```
var vcfBlob = new Blob(vcfBytes.split('\n').map(function(x) { return x + '\n' }));
```

and then passing that blob to a file saver

```
saveAs(vcfBlob, "hello world.vcf")
```

Answer (score -1):

You might want to try generating it on the back-end, using NodeJS / TS package:
[npm/ez-vcard](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ez-vcard); [GitHub/Maxim-Mazurok/ez-vcard](https://github.com/Maxim-Mazurok/ez-vcard)

Also, see [readme](https://github.com/Maxim-Mazurok/ez-vcard#readme) and [example](https://github.com/Maxim-Mazurok/ez-vcard/tree/a6dee01e4171565a66f0f8eb76ab0c9c53fb8b06/example) for usage.